# Why is Tesseract unable to detect the single digit in that image?

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this image, and I'm trying to read it with Tesseract:

[image]

My code is like that:

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
```

But, what I get is only `LOW: 56`. So, Tesseract is unable to read the `1` in the first line. I've tried to specify also a whitelist of only digits like

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(im, config="tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.")
```

and to process the image with an erosion but nothing works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) is your "holy scripture" when working with Tesseract. Especially, the [page segmentation method](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method) should always be explicitly set. Here (as most of the times), I'd opt for `--psm 6`:

> Assume a single uniform block of text.

Even without further preprocessing of your image, you already get the desired result:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

image = cv2.imread('gBrcd.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 6')
print(text.replace('\f', ''))
# 1
# LOW: 56
```

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
OpenCV:        4.5.2
pytesseract:   5.0.0-alpha.20201127
----------------------------------------
```